# extends BaseAdapter results are overwrite previous ArrayList Items

Tags: android, arraylist, baseadapter

i have a DateApapter class like this..

```
 public class DateAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    { 
    ...
    }
```

i call this DateApapter in 12 different places from my "mainActivity" by using `constructor` and store this result in a DateApapter object "mDefaultAdapter " like this..

```
mDefaultAdapter = new DateAdapter(this,days,sysDate,disablePastDays, selectedDateTypeDf);
```

and stored this various results of mDefaultAdapter in ArrayList like this..

```
ArrayList<DateAdapter> mDefaultAdapterList = new ArrayList<DateAdapter>();
mDefaultAdapterList.add(mDefaultAdapter);
```

now coming to the problem,

- In my 1st call DateAdapter constructor , it returns January month
  details and I add this result(January) to ArrayList its works fine.
  Now the ArrayList has one Item, that is January details.
- but when i call 2nd result(February) to arrayList its overwrite 1st
  result also.    Now the ArrayList has two Items, both of the items
  are February    details.
- That means Last result of DateAdapter is filled the whole ArrayList.
  Finally i got December details only from ArrayList.

Why DateAdapter results are overwrite in previous ArrayList Items? 
I am not using any Static variables or methods in whole program.
Please help me to fix this problem. Thanks..

Comment: Why would you need 12 adapters in a single Activity? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Benito i want to store 12 months details for ViewPager Fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake.. The problem is Illegal object reference overwrite my previous ArrayList Items.
I saved myself by making a separate object for Date Adapter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what's happening with your adapter. Maybe you're using the same `ArrayList` object with all the adapters.

But I think you should reconsider your approach.

Here's what I would do.

1- Store the calendar events in an `SQLite` database.

2- In your `FragmentPagerAdapter`, pass the position to your Calendar `Fragment`.

3- In your Calendar `Fragment`, retrieve the position ( 0 : January - 11 : December) and query your database to retrieve the events.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll use this concept in my next project.